# How can I get mypy to use types from typings directory, but not report errors from the typings directory?

Tags: python, static-analysis, mypy

I want mypy to check the directory `src`

`src` uses a 3rd party library without typing and not in typeshed. So I made a `typings` directory with type stubs for this 3rd party library. But it's a big library and I can't make complete typing for all of it, so I just made typing for the API that I use.

If I use `mypy src`, it doesn't find the typings. It reports problems because of that.

If I use `mypy src typings`, it doesn't report the problems in `src`, but it reports problems in `typings`.

I want it to use typing information from `typings` to check `src`, but not report errors from `typings`.